# marionette nested layouts unable to show view

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In my application, I am creating nested layout views, as below:

=> a app layout view which has header and body regions

```
var AppLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    el : "body",
    regions: {
        headerRegion: "#ecp_header",
        bodyRegion: "#ecp_body",
        contentRegion: "#home"
    },
```

=> dashboard layout view which is nested inside body region of app layout

```
ECPApp.DashboardLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    el: "#home",
    regions: {
        menuRegion: "#left-menu",
        contentRegion: "#usr-dashboard"
    },
```

The parent layout (applayout) creates n adds a set of bootstrap tab content panes to the DOM, so the child layout view (dashboard lyt) can use the first tab pane (#home) to show a sidebar menu and content portion within this first tab pane.

I am rendering both the layouts as below:
applayout:

The app layout renders correctly and attaches the required header and footer elements to the DOM. After rendering the app layout, I trigger a boostrap.tab.shown event.  In the handler of this event I am trying to draw the child layout view (dashboard lyt).

```
{
  render: function() {
    // load and attach templates for header and body regions.
    var headerView = new HeaderView({model:session});
    this.headerRegion.show(headerView);

    var bodyView = new BodyView({model:session});
    this.bodyRegion.show(bodyView);

    // finally trigger a bootstrap tab show event, so
    // the rest of the content will be drawn on tabshown evt.
    headerView.$el.find('a#home-tab').tab('show');
  },

  onTabShown: function() {
    var self = this;
    // create an instance of nested layout view and show it.
    var dbLytView = new UserDashboardLayoutView();
    dbLytView.render();
    //self.contentRegion.show(dbLytView);
  }
}
```

Now comes the problem, when I call applayout.contentregion.show(dashboardlyt), The child layout's render gets called and it loads a set of templates for its internal regions (left menu and dashboard content).  But as soon as the render call returns to the caller (parent lyt) it tries to do a show(...) of the rendered view, the DOM node is disappearing.

Below is the screenshot just before the child lyt render returns. We can see that the child lyt has added its elements correctly.
[image]

Once the render returns and the parent completes the show method, the elements are disappearing.

DOM elements before the render call returns:
[image]

After the call returns and parent show executes
[image]

It can be seen that the highlighted node in the above pic, is not available any more, after the show method executes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you are overwriting the render method in your layoutview, you shouldn't have to overwrite render.  Start by moving the code in the render method to a onShow or onRender method.

Comment: Additional information: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.itemview.html#itemview-render

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Moved the render code to onRender() and removed the render() fn, so base class render will do its work.  Now my onRender() is being called, but the same result.

Comment: Just to add that this works, if I don't call outerlayout.show(region, inner_layout), in my outer_layout, but when I call inner_layout.render(), Either there is a bug in nested layout, or I am not calling it correctly.  It didn't matter whether I overwrote the inner layout's render, or called my code in onRender(). The behavior is the same.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems #home is a child of #ecp_body and both elements have a region attached to them. So if the bodyRegion of the AppLayoutView gets updated it overwrites or completely removes #home. On top of that #home is the `el` property of the ECPApp.DashboardLayoutView. So essentially a View and a Region are bound to the same element. Removing `el: '#home` from ECPApp.DashboardLayoutView and showing this layout with `self.contentRegion.show(new UserDashboardLayoutView())` might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Found the problem.  I am trying to call show() with a region which was not available in DOM when appLayout was instantiated.  To verify this is the case, I tried showing the dashboardLayout view to bodyRegion (existing one), and it works!  But I need 2 attach to content Region and I am sure at the point of attaching this contentRegion's el exists in DOM, even though it wasn't available during appLayout creation.. But it fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem seems to be **Region Availability** as defined here: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.8.8/marionette.layout.html. Trying to find a solution... :(

Comment: Can you post the template for AppLayoutView?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79269/discussion-between-mupparthy-ravindranath-and-jacob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacob is right, declaring the render method is totally the wrong approach.

It should be onRender.

```
{
  onRender: function() {
    // load and attach templates for header and body regions.
    var headerView = new HeaderView({model:session});
    this.headerRegion.show(headerView);

    var bodyView = new BodyView({model:session});
    this.bodyRegion.show(bodyView);

    // finally trigger a bootstrap tab show event, so
    // the rest of the content will be drawn on tabshown evt.
    headerView.$el.find('a#home-tab').tab('show');
  },
```